# Token based Authentication - Authorization in Angular 4 app with ASP.Net Core API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have below requirement to build my app in Angular4 and ASP.Net Core API.

1. I am going to use JWT token based authentication - authorization.
2. There can be internal users accessing this application as well as users from outside network.
3. For internal users just need to read the windows logged in ID and get the roles from the database and create token.
4. For Outside users I need to navigate to login page to enter userName and Password to be validated.

How can I read the windows logged in UserName in ASP.Net Core for the coming request from Angular 4?

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

We don't think using Angular that runs in web browsers is allowed to read logged in user of windows machine.  You can create an entry for that same user in backend and validate by entering username and password.

Comment: Requirement is to enter username password by external users only. Internal user's id should be passed to API where token is created with roles defined in database.

Comment: Do you think any other ways we can achieve the same?